# two-way data binding inside attribute directive that requires element directive

Tags: angularjs

I have an element directive (`e-dir`) and an attribute directive (`a-dir`) on the same element:

```
<e-dir a-dir attr="msg"></e-dir>
```

I pass `msg` into `e-dir`'s isolate scope via the `attr` attribute:

```
app.directive('eDir', function eDir($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      attr: '='
    }
  };
});
```

In this way, `msg` is bound (two-ways) with `$scope.attr` (in `EDirCtrl`) or `scope.attr` (in `e-dir`'s link function).

Is there a simple way I can achieve the same two-way data-binding inside `a-dir`'s directive? Or would you recommend another, simpler approach?

The closest thing I've been able to come up with is to set `eDirCtrl.attr = $scope.attr;` inside `e-dir`'s controller (`EDirCtrl`):

```
app.directive('eDir', function eDir($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      attr: '='
    },
    controller: function EDirCtrl($scope) {
      var eDirCtrl = this;
      eDirCtrl.attr = $scope.attr;
    },
    controllerAs: 'eDirCtrl'
  };
});
```

Then, have `a-dir` require `e-dir`, and access `attr` via `e-dir`'s controller (`eDirCtrl.attr`):

```
app.directive('aDir', function aDir($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'eDir',
    link: linkFn
  };

  function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, eDirCtrl) {
    eDirCtrl.attr = 'eDirCtrl.attr';
  }
});
```

But, it's not bound two-ways. As you can see this code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.msg = 'initial message';
})

app.directive('eDir', function eDir($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      attr: '='
    },
    template: '<div>$scope.attr: {{attr}}</div>'+
    '<div>eDirCtrl.attr: {{eDirCtrl.attr}}</div>',
    controller: function EDirCtrl($scope) {
      var eDirCtrl = this;
      eDirCtrl.attr = $scope.attr;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.attr = 'changing $scope.attr also changes msg';
      }, 2000);
    },
    controllerAs: 'eDirCtrl'
  };
}); 

app.directive('aDir', function aDir($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'eDir',
    link: linkFn
  };

  function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, eDirCtrl) {
    $timeout(function() {
      eDirCtrl.attr = 'changing eDirCtrl.attr does not effect $scope.attr or msg';
    }, 4000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  msg: <input type="text" ng-model="msg"><br>
  <e-dir a-dir attr="msg"></e-dir>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the two-way binding isn't working is that `attr` is being bound to a string rather than an object. In JavaScript, primitives (booleans, numbers, strings) are immutable, so when you change one, the previous instance is discarded and a new one is used. This breaks Angular's two-way binding and any changes to `scope.msg` are not propagated through `attr` into the directive.

You can get this to work as expected by setting `msg` on an object e.g. `scope.test.msg` and binding `attr` to `test` (the object) rather than `msg` (a string).

I've updated your code snippet to do this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = {msg : 'initial message'};
})

app.directive('eDir', function eDir($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      attr: '='
    },
    template: '<div>$scope.attr: {{attr.msg}}</div>'+
    '<div>eDirCtrl.attr: {{eDirCtrl.attr.msg}}</div>',
    controller: function EDirCtrl($scope) {
      var eDirCtrl = this;
      eDirCtrl.attr = $scope.attr;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.attr.msg = 'changing $scope.attr also changes msg';
      }, 2000);
    },
    controllerAs: 'eDirCtrl'
  };
}); 

app.directive('aDir', function aDir($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'eDir',
    link: linkFn
  };

  function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, eDirCtrl) {
    $timeout(function() {
      eDirCtrl.attr.msg = 'changing eDirCtrl.attr does not effect $scope.attr or msg';
    }, 4000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  msg: <input type="text" ng-model="test.msg"><br>
  <e-dir a-dir attr="test"></e-dir>
</div>
```